# trouble with page_id & highlighting current page

Tags: php, pages, css, javascript, links

I'm using the below code to highlight the page name/gallery shown when the corresponding link is clicked on. My challenge is that regardless of what link I click, only the very first link(`page_id=24`/Haagen-Dazs) is highlighted. Any ideas what's causing the issue?

Thanks.

[live site](http://urbanpalate.com/instyle-mag-ming-by-mango/)

CSS
`.active { 
    border: 1px solid #ff893b;
}`

HTML/PHP/JAVA
`

```
<p>
    <a href="?page_id=24" <?php if ($page_id=='24'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> H&auml;agen Dazs</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=26" <?php if ($page_id=='26'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> Hugo Boss Rodeo Drive</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=28" <?php if ($page_id=='28'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> Ford</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=30" <?php if ($page_id=='30'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> MOCA Contemporaries</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=32" <?php if ($page_id=='32'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> XBOX 360 Halo 3 Sneak Preview</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=34" <?php if ($page_id=='34'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> Saddlerock Smith &amp; Basso Weddings</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=36" <?php if ($page_id=='36'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> Christie&apos;s</a><br/>
    <a href="?page_id=42" <?php if ($page_id=='42'){echo 'class="active"';} ?>> Instyle Magazine + Ming by Mango</a>
</p>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
      $('a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

     });

    });   

</script>

</div><!-- end client-list -->`
```

Comment: Had you checked that `$page_id` holds expected and correct value at that point?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but links do lead to the proper pages.

Comment: Your code assumes that `$page_id` variable holds ID of current page. You should verify that it really does (for example by echoing its value).

Comment: Can you provide an example? Sorry- I am still new to this.

Comment: `<?php var_dump( $page_id ); ?>`

Comment: Thank you, could you please provide context? Again, still new.

Comment: You are recommended to have at least basic PHP skills to mess with things like this. :) Comments are not for extended explanations, please look up relevant bits in PHP documentation or drop by [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a WP Nav menu or the built in APIs instead. They all have current cat/active/parent highlighting on posts/pages, all out of the box

Comment: Menus are not available to me through Appearance > Menus (per the codex)?

Comment: Thats because you need to indicate that your theme supports them via `add_theme_support`

Answer (score 1):

Add Menu by using register_nav_menu in theme's function.php file.

you can see Appearance > Menus.